# Wordpress: How can I show a different html only on Safari?

Tags: wordpress, safari

I'd like to show different html when someone access a Wordpress site with Safari.
So I wrote this code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <div class="main">
        <div id="content" class="reserve-cont">
            <?php if ($is_safari) : ?>
                <div class="page-safari">
                    <p>Please press<br class="only-sp"><a href="https://bra-bra-bra-example" target="_blank">here</a>!<p>
                </div>
            <?php else: ?>
                <div class="reservation inner">
                    <iframe src="https://bra-bra-bra-example" max-width="800" height="618"></iframe>
                </div><!-- /inner -->
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div><!-- /content -->
    </div><!-- /main -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

But when I see the site with iPhone, Chrome also shows me the html for Safari.
With Android phone and PC, it doesn't happen.

Does anyone know how I can figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

```
$is_safari
```

This is wordpress global variable, so to access it, you have to globalize variable with `global $is_safari;` on top of your template.
[Global Variables](https://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables)

About IPhone Chrome. Not exactly sure, but maybe ios chrome is still using same rendering webkit, that safari uses and that is the reason why site is detecting it as safari.